# Difference between if <obj> and if <obj> is not None

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

In writing some XML parsing code, I received the warning:

```
FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
```

where I used `if <elem>:` to check if a value was found for a given element.

Can someone elaborate on the difference between `if <obj>:` vs `if <obj> is not None:` and why Python cares which I use?

I almost always use the former because it's shorter and not a double-negative, but often see the latter in other people's source code.

Comment: Note: currently [`if <elem>:` is equivalent to `if <elem>.has_children():`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/43f27e69bc29/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l231) that is quite different from `if <elem> is not None:`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`if obj is not None` test whether the object is not None.  `if obj` tests whether `bool(obj)` is True.

There are many objects which are not None but for which `bool(obj)` is False: for instance, an empty list, an empty dict, an empty set, an empty string. . .

Use `if obj is not None` when you want to test if an object is not None.  Use `if obj` only if you want to test for general "falseness" -- whose definition is object-dependent.

Comment: For reference, here are all the [falsey values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: Objects returned from lxml etree `find` behave strangely. You will get this `FutureWarning` for nodes returned from, e.g. `node = root.find('.//tag/')`. [More details in this article I wrote](http://yummycoding.tumblr.com/post/82299053082/lxml-and-futurewarning) but gist is that `node` would be falsey if it had no children, whether or not a node matching the pattern was found. So `if node` means "Matching node exists **and** match has children". This is why you are warned to be explicit: use `len(node)` to mean "Has children"; use `node is not None` to mean "Matching node exists".

Comment: To add to @BurhanKhalid's comment, here are the [falsey values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for Python 3.

Answer (score 10):

This answer addresses the FutureWarning specifically.

When lxml was first written, the `lxml.etree._Element` was considered falsey if it had no children.

As a result, this can happen:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> 
>>> root = etree.fromstring('<body><h1>Hello</h1></body>')
>>> print root
<Element body at 0x41d7680>
>>> print "root is not Falsey" if root else "root is Falsey"
<string>:1: FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions. Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
root is not Falsey
>>> # that's odd, a warning
>>> h1 = root.find('.//h1')
>>> print h1
<Element h1 at 0x41d7878>
>>> print "h1 is not Falsey" if h1 else "h1 is Falsey"
h1 is Falsey
>>> # huh, that is weird! In most of python, an object is rarely False
>>> # we did see a warning though, didn't we?
>>> # let's see how the different elements output
>>> print "root is not None" if root is not None else "root is None"
root is not None
>>> print "h1 is not None" if h1 is not None else "h1 is None"
h1 is not None
>>> print "Length of root is ", len(root)
Length of root is  1
>>> print "Length of h1 is ", len(h1)
Length of h1 is  0
>>> # now to look for something that's not there!
>>> h2 = root.find('.//h2')
>>> print h2
None
>>> print "h2 is not Falsey" if h2 else "h2 is Falsey"
h2 is Falsey
>>> print "h2 is not None" if h2 is not None else "h2 is None"
h2 is None
>>> print "Length of h2 is ", len(h2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
Length of h2 is  >>>
```

lxml has been promising for 7+ years that this change is going to happen (after going through several versions) but has never followed through on the threat, no doubt because of how central lxml is and fears it would break a lot of existing code.

However, to be both explicit and sure you don't make a mistake, **never use `if obj` or `if not obj` if that object has a type of `lxml.etree._Element`.**

Instead, use one of the following checks:

```
obj = root.find('.//tag')

if obj is not None:
    print "Object exists" 

if obj is None:
    print "Object does not exist/was not found"

if len(obj): # warning: if obj is None (no match found) TypeError
    print "Object has children"

if not len(obj): # warning: if obj is None (no match found) TypeError
    print "Object does not have children"
```

Answer (score 1):

For a full explanation consider the following example:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def is_truthy(x):
>>>    return "Those sweed words!" if x else "All lies!"
>>> is_truthy(None)
'All lies!'
>>> is_truthy(1)
'Those sweed words!'
>>> is_truthy([])
'All lies!'
>>> is_truthy(object())
'Those sweed words!'
```

What's happening in `is_truthy()` ? Let's find out. Running `dis.dis(is_truthy)` gives you:

```
   2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
               3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10
               6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('The pure word')
               9 RETURN_VALUE        
         >>   10 LOAD_CONST               2 ('All lies!')
              13 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see `x` is pushed onto the stack, then `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` is executed. This will take the jump to first push and then return the right answer.

`POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` is defined in [ceval.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aeb3faaf4754/Python/ceval.c#l2512):

```
TARGET(POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE) {
    PyObject *cond = POP();
    int err;
    if (cond == Py_True) {
        Py_DECREF(cond);
        FAST_DISPATCH();
    }
    if (cond == Py_False) {
        Py_DECREF(cond);
        JUMPTO(oparg);
        FAST_DISPATCH();
    }
    err = PyObject_IsTrue(cond);
    Py_DECREF(cond);
    if (err > 0)
        err = 0;
    else if (err == 0)
        JUMPTO(oparg);
    else
        goto error;
    DISPATCH();
```

As you can see, if the object consumed by `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` is already either `True` or `False`, the answer is simple. Otherwise the interpreter tries to find out if the object is *truthy* by calling `PyObject_IsTrue()` which is defined in the [object protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html). The [code in object.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aeb3faaf4754/Objects/object.c#l1357) shows you exactly how it works:

```
PyObject_IsTrue(PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;
    if (v == Py_True)
        return 1;
    if (v == Py_False)
        return 0;
    if (v == Py_None)
        return 0;
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_number != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_bool != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_bool)(v);
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_length)(v);
    else if (v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence != NULL &&
             v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length != NULL)
        res = (*v->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_length)(v);
    else
        return 1;
    /* if it is negative, it should be either -1 or -2 */
    return (res > 0) ? 1 : Py_SAFE_DOWNCAST(res, Py_ssize_t, int);
}
```

Again, if the object is just `True` or `False` themselves, the answer is simple. `None` is also considered false. Then various protocols like the [number protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html), the [mapping protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/mapping.html) and the [sequence protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html) are checked. Otherwise the object is considered true.

To wrap it up: `x` is considered true if it is `True`, true according to the number, mapping or sequence protocol or some other kind of object. If you want your object to evaluate to false, you can do so by implementing any of said protocols, see the provided links.

Comparing to `None` like in `if x is None` is an explicit comparison. The logic above does not apply.

Comment: [The docs define Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)  quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `if x` is sort of interesting:

```
In [1]: def truthy(x):
...:     if x:
...:         return 'Truthy!'
...:     else:
...:         return 'Not truthy!'
...:     

In [2]: truthy(True)
Out[2]: 'Truthy!'

In [3]: truthy(False)
Out[3]: 'Not truthy!'

In [4]: truthy(0)
Out[4]: 'Not truthy!'

In [5]: truthy(1)
Out[5]: 'Truthy!'

In [6]: truthy(None)
Out[6]: 'Not truthy!'

In [7]: truthy([])
Out[7]: 'Not truthy!'

In [8]: truthy('')
Out[8]: 'Not truthy!'
```

So, for example, statements under the conditional `if x` will **not** execute if `x` is 0, None, the empty list, or the empty string. On the other hand `if x is not None` will only apply when `x` is exactly `None`.