# if elem vs. elem is not none

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Elementtree to parse an XML document I had the following conditional

```
pl = xml_task.find(namespace_tag('PredecessorLink'))

if pl :
    ....
```

But Python gave me a warning/notice that it should instead be

```
if pl is not None :
    ...
```

I understand that there are differences between the first and second conditional but I don't understand the following warning:

```
FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions. 
Use specific 'len (elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.
```

Comment: See second bullet point at http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @sapi thanks, found the answer regarding Etree in the answers to that question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24893800/3812142).